# Deploy Rails with Chef Solo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, chef-infra, capistrano, chef-solo

I'm trying to follow the guide, [Provisioning a Rails Server Using Chef](http://vladigleba.com/blog/2014/07/28/provisioning-a-rails-server-using-chef-part-1-introduction-to-chef-solo/), deploy my setup my rails server using Chef Solo. When I try to run the setup_vps.sh in part the server keeps asking me for the root password. When I `ctl-c` out of that it ask me for the password for `deploy` user and doesn't accept that password either. Both the user have already been `ssh-copy-id` previously and shouldn't even ask for the password.

#### 0.0.0.0.json (not the real ip)

```
{
  "group": "wheel",
  "port": 22,

  "user": {
    "name": "deploy",
    "password": "$1$mywonderfullpassword/x/"
  },


  "run_list": [
    "recipe[main]",
    "recipe[main::users]",
    "recipe[main::ssh]",
    "recipe[main::nodejs]",
    "recipe[main::rbenv]",
    "recipe[main::redis]",
    "recipe[main::nginx]",
    "recipe[main::app]"
  ]
}
```

#### setup_vps.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# check for correct number of arguments
if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <user> <ip> <port>"
  exit 1
fi

# set variables
USER=$1
IP=$2
PORT=$3

# upload key for root
# ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@$IP

# install chef
cd config/chef && knife solo prepare root@$IP

# execute the run list
knife solo cook root@$IP

# upload key for user
# ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -p $PORT $USER@$IP

# upload app
cd ../.. && cap production setup:all

# restart nginx
ssh -p $PORT -t $USER@$IP 'sudo service nginx restart'
```

#### app recipe

```
# create www directory
directory '/var/www' do
  user node['user']['name']
  group node['group']
  mode 0755
end

# create shared directory structure for app
path = "/var/www/#{node['app']}/shared/config"
execute "mkdir -p #{path}" do
  user node['user']['name']
  group node['group']
  creates path
end

# create database.yml file
template "#{path}/database.yml" do
  source 'database.yml.erb'
  mode 0640
  owner node['user']['name']
  group node['group']
end

puma_config "#{node['app']}"

# # set unicorn config
# template "/etc/init.d/puma_#{node['app']}" do
#   source 'puma.sh.erb'
#   mode 0755
#   owner node['user']['name']
#   group node['group']
# end
#
# # add init script link
# execute "update-rc.d puma_#{node['app']} defaults" do
#   not_if "ls /etc/rc2.d | grep puma_#{node['app']}"
# end
```

#### config git:(knife-solo) ✗ ./setup_server.sh deploy 0.0.0.0 22

```
./setup_server.sh: line 18: cd: config/chef: No such file or directory
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-11.18.12/lib/chef/data_bag_item.rb:161: warning: circular argument reference - data_bag
Running Chef on 0.0.0.0...
Checking Chef version...
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:67:in `initialize': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:84:in `initialize': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
root@0.0.0.0's password: 
Stage not set, please call something such as `cap production deploy`, where production is a stage you have defined.
deploy@0.0.0.0's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
deploy@0.0.0.0's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
deploy@0.0.0.0's password:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That guide is very out of date and not recommended. See https://github.com/poise/application_examples/blob/master/recipes/todo_rails.rb for a more modern example.